# Android Volley request queue does not run all requests

Tags: android, android-volley, intentservice

On some devices my Volley request queue does not run all the network requests I added to the queue. I tried two approaches to this, approach one:

1) A recursive method where subsequent network requests were called in the `onResponse` method of the previous request.

The service that starts this recursion is killed by the system before it finishes, but on some devices the Volley request queue can still finish this method. On other devices only one network request is made and the subsequent ones are not.

2) A for loop where all the request objects are added to the request queue before any one of them makes a network call.

On some devices the request queue still behaves like I want it to, on other devices it is a hit or miss.

I use a singleton to maintain my request queue, so this shouldn't have anything to do with the `IntentService` being destroyed by the system

insight appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use an `IntentService`, it is destroyed as soon as the `handleIntent` method returns. if no activity is running at this time you app terminates, and your singleton disappears.

With volley you don't need an `IntentService`, since Volley handles the asynchronism for you.

Use a standard service with `START_STICKY` as a return, and don't forget to `stopSelf` when you have completed your requests.

Comment: hmm, actually the problem is still happening. My Volley threads start before onStartCommend returns, and after it returns it may sometimes kill the singleton. But this is with activities still running too.

Comment: this is weird. How long does it take?

Comment: well it is actually a multipart upload with bytes split into 14 - 40 parts. I know what Google has said about Volley handling "large" payloads, but this is a highly modified volley to handle multipart uploads. Essentially though, byte chunks are added to individual requests (of type MultipartRequest) and these requests are added to the request queue like normal requests. Volley uploads them and the server likes it, but on some devices, sometimes, the requestQueue singleton gets killed or something. Other devices just churn straight through the whole upload queue.